# Insertar contenido html en Outlook

Tags: html

¿Es posible insertar contenido html en un correo Outlook? ya que necesito insertar imágenes.

Comment: Hola Daniel, ¿te refieres **Outlook** como la página de correo electrónico o **Outlook** como cliente de correos electrónicos?

Comment: Hola David, me refiero a Outlook como la página de correo electrónico.

Comment: Si es posible, pero tiene que enviarse desde un servidor de correo electrónicos o puedes hacerlo desde un lenguaje de _Backend_, es decir, `PHP`, `Python`, entre otros.

Comment: Ok perfecto, nosotros utilizamos java, pero, se nos hace muy difícil insertar imágenes por este medio. y al saber que si se puede insertar HTML, ¿de que forma lo haría?, Gracias.

Comment: Ahora mismo estoy redactando una respuesta. Estoy utilizando PHP como ejemplo, pero con ejemplos sencillos para que lo puedas extrapolar a `Java`.

Comment: Me parece excelente, estaré esperando tus ejemplos.

Comment: Saludos Daniel, en el sitio he visto buena cantidad de preguntas relacionadas a tu pregunta, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=enviar+correo+outlook y si le quitas outlook https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=enviar+correo hay más de mil publicaciones

Comment: Vale, Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me estoy guiando por la información que me brindaron y ahora tengo muchos recursos para realizar lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

### Insertar HTML a correos electrónicos

Es posible insertar HTML desde cualquier lenguaje  de lado del servidor. En este caso, se utilizará `PHP` para reproducir un ejemplo sencillo que permitirá extrapolar su lógica a cualquier a otro lenguaje de programación.

En dicho escenario, se asumirá que se tiene un archivo HTML denominado `documento.html` que es al que le extraeremos su código para enviarlo a un correo electrónico. Para ello, se utilizará [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents).

El valor devuelto por la función [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents) se almacenará en una variable denominada `$mensaje`:

```php
$mensaje = file_get_contents( "documento.html" );
```

Además, de definir las cabeceras:

```php
// Se indica la versión MIME a utilizar:
$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

// Se indica que se enviará un correo HTML con una 
// codificación de caracteres UTF-8:
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

Bien, teniendo claro esto, se utilizará la función [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php), que es la que permitirá enviar correos electrónicos desde PHP.

Esta es la descripción de dicha función de acuerdo al [Sitio Oficial de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php):

> mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] ) : bool

Quedaría así utilizando la función [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php):

```php
mail( "correodestino@ejemplo.com", "Título del correo (asunto)", $mensaje, $cabecera );
```

Teniendo claro todo lo anteriormente expuesto en esta respuesta, se reúne en un solo lugar los fragmentos de código dispersos en cada área explicada, es decir:

```php
// Código HTML en la variable $mensaje:
$mensaje = file_get_contents( "documento.html" );

// En ella se indica que se enviará un correo HTML
// con codificación UTF-8:
$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

// Y finalmente se ejecuta la función mail:
mail( "correodestino@ejemplo.com", "Título del correo (asunto)", $mensaje, $cabecera );
```

**Importante:** no se debe tomar este ejemplo como la mejor forma de enviar correos electrónicos HTML, ya que su objetivo es orientativo. Si desea enviar correos electrónicos HTML más complejos desde PHP considere realizar un recorrido a [Mail_Mime](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime)